# Reduce vertical whitespace with elsarticle

Tags: positioning, elsarticle, white-space

I am trying to reduce the amount of vertical whitespace in `elsarticle`. Specifically, I would like to move the entire abstract (summary) box up.
Simply adding `\vspace{-3em}` right after `\begin{abstract}` moves the text but not the horizontal rulers or the "Summary" heading.

Any ideas?

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\abstracttitle{Summary}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{
    Reduce vertical whitespace with elsarticle
}

\author[]{Authors...}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section*{Introduction}
\noindent
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That vertical space (36pt) is set by the class to meet Elsevier specifications.

Nevertheless
the license of `elsarticle.cls` allows modifications of the code.

> It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
> License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
> later version.  The latest version of this license is in
>
> http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
>
> 5. If you are not the Current Maintainer of the Work, you may modify your
>    copy of the Work, thus creating a Derived Work based on the Work, and
>    compile this Derived Work, thus creating a Compiled Work based on the
>    Derived Work.

To reduce the space add the following patch to your code

```
%**************************************
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}%
{\vskip36pt} % original vertical space 36 pt
{\vskip0pt} % minimum vertical space  <<<<<<<<<<<
{}
{}
%%**************************************
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}     

%**************************************
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}%
{\vskip36pt} % original vertical space 36 pt
{\vskip0pt} % minimum vertical space  <<<<<<<<<<<
{}
{}
%%**************************************

\abstracttitle{Summary}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{
            Reduce vertical whitespace with elsarticle
        }
        
        \author[]{Authors...}
        
        \begin{abstract}
            \noindent
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{abstract}
    \end{frontmatter}
    
    \section*{Introduction}
    \noindent
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Any idea what are the two empty `{}` for? I initially copied your solution without them and it did not work. Very neat solution though. Thanks.

Comment: @Shahar They are part of the `\patchcmd`. To do something if the patch succeed or not. Usually used to send messages to the console like Patch done! .